# Django not rendering html with tags assigned in python code

Tags: python, django

I want to display the chemical formula of compound with subscript. I have a list of compounds and few of them should be written using subscript. I wrote the following code:

```
def contains_number(string):
    new_string = ''
    int_str_list = list(map(str, list(range(9))))
    for item in string:
        if item in int_str_list:
            new_string += '<sub> '+item+' </sub>'
        else:
            new_string += item
    return new_string
```

This code works and when I pass string like Fe2O3, I get the output like:
`Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>` which is what I want.

However, when I pass this as a context variable to Django template, it is not rendered as Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> but as text `Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>` .

Since I am new to Django, I am missing something, I know.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Those two outputs look the same to me, whats different? What code are you using to pass as context?

Comment: That was my thought exactly. It is rendered in browser, however as, `Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>` ., which if put into plain html will give the subscripted text.

Comment: You should probably turn escape off in django template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape

Comment: @stellasia : Wonderful, that was the culprit.  Thank you very much. Please post it as your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: if the `item` is user input, you should escape it first, then you can disable autoescape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to HTML tag [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape). Turn the autoescape off in the django templates and it should work fine:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ you_text }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Django autoescapes template variables. If you look at the source of the generated output, you will see something like `&lt;sub&gt;2...`.

**Do not just turn autoescaping if the parameter `string` is user generated input!**

Auto-escaping prevents XSS attacks, so turning it off might fix your problem, but can lead to a security vulnerability if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

```
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


def contains_number(string):
    new_string = ''
    for item in string:
        if item.isdigit():
            # we know item is a number, so no need to escape it
            new_string += '<sub> '+ item +' </sub>'  
        else:
            new_string += escape(item)
    # we built new_string from safe parts, so we can mark it as
    # safe to prevent autoescaping
    return mark_safe(new_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

... or you can use `safe` filter:

```
{{ your_text|safe }}
```

I believe in most cases it's safer than `autoescape` blocks (no risk you'll leave unescaped something you have to escape).